# Find and return a data-structure's nested value by a given keypath

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parsing, data-structures, keypaths

So, we are working with data-objects parsed from JSON-strings.

We did several exercises (8 out of 10 well done), but I'm stuck with the ninth.

The assignment says:

> Find and return the value at the given nested path in the <strike>JSON</strike> [data]-object.

And what it gives us is to start with:

```
function findNestedValue(obj, path) {
}
```

The object we are working with/on is:

```
const sampleDate = {
  people: [{
    name: 'Alice',
    age: 30,
  }, {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 25,
  }, {
    name: 'Charlie',
    age: 35,
  }],
  city: 'New York',
  year: 2023,
};
```

If I look in the test.js file (where there is the code for npm to test the results of our function), it says:

```
test('findNestedValue should find and return the value at the given nested path', () => {

  expect(findNestedValue(sampleData, 'people[0].name')).toBe('Alice');
  expect(findNestedValue(sampleData, 'city')).toBe('New York');
});
```

Honestly, I'm lost, completely. Any tip? I'm lost, lost lost.

Any advice?

```
 for (let key in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      for (let i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
        if (obj[key][i] === path)
    else {
        if (obj[key] === path)
```

I was trying something like that, but I'm really just wandering in the dark.

Comment: btw, you have no json object, becaus of [JSON](https://json.org/) is a sting which represents a javascript literal. to get a value of a json, you need to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a generated function. In other cases make sure your path values aren't 3rd party to avoid XSS attacks:

```js
function findNestedValue(obj, path) {
    try {
        return new Function('obj', 'return obj.' + path)(obj);
    } catch (_) {}
}
const o = { 
people: [ 
{ name: 'Alice', age: 30 }, 
{ name: 'Bob', age: 25 }, 
{ name: 'Charlie', age: 35 }, 
], 
city: 'New York', 
year: 2023, };
console.log(findNestedValue(o, 'people[0].name'));
console.log(findNestedValue(o, 'city'));
```

Comment: `eval` is more handy.

Comment: @NinaScholz and more unsafe

Comment: it is not more unsafe. it is exactly the same.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Using the Function constructor does not make it any more safe. The main reason to prefer it over `eval` is performance, not to merely avoid the word `eval` appearing in your code.

Comment: @Unmitigated i've mentioned that in test like the OP intends using it's safe imho. if not please provide an example

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I'm referring to your comment about `eval`. Using `eval` would be simpler here and just as valid if assuming input is not user-provided.

Comment: @NinaScholz it's not. eval has access to all scopes, Function has only access to globalThis: `{
  const inject = 'inject';
  console.log( eval('inject') );
  console.log(new Function('', 'return inject')());
}`. this makes Functions definitely more safe

Comment: @Unmitigated check my above comment, eval isn't not safe since it can clash with outer scope variables in some cases. Function doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev If you are considering those as problems, then clearly the assumption of valid input does not hold, in which case the Function constructor also allows arbitrary code to execute. Also, consider `eval?.('inject')` (although not exactly relevant for this specific case).

Comment: Within an controlled environment and with a very specific task like going for an objects nested value by a keypath, an evaluating generated function is not unsafe. It even outperforms other string-split and array-reduce solutions and avoids entirely the effort of a possible need to cover bulletproof evaluation and parsing of complex keypath grammars. If done with regex such a task easily gives birth to patterns like that ... [`/(?:\[(?:(\d+)|(?:(?<quote1>['"])(.*?)\k<quote1>))\]\.?)|(?:\.?(?<quote2>['"])(.*?)\k<quote2>\.?)|\./`](https://regex101.com/r/BVqDyV/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could first replace all square brackets, then split on `.` to get all elements of the path. `Array#reduce` can be used to access each key in turn.

```js
function findNestedValue(obj, path) {
  return path.replaceAll('[', '.').replaceAll(']', '').split('.')
    .reduce((acc, curr) => acc?.[curr], obj);
}
const o = { 
people: [ 
{ name: 'Alice', age: 30 }, 
{ name: 'Bob', age: 25 }, 
{ name: 'Charlie', age: 35 }, 
], 
city: 'New York', 
year: 2023, };
console.log(findNestedValue(o, 'people[0].name'));
console.log(findNestedValue(o, 'city'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It actually solves the problem, but not in the way I'm supposed to do it. It's too complicated (or it seems to me) related to the knowledge we have until now.

Plus, we should not know that what we are looking for is `people[0].name` and `city`

Comment: @Litmanen84 "but not in the way I'm supposed to do it" - In what way are you supposed to do it? "Plus, we should not know that what we are looking for is people[0].name and city" - What do you mean? Those are just examples in the snippet to show the code works.

Comment: Your way is obviously perfect, but too advanced for what I/we know at the moment. Tha part ".reduce((acc, curr) => acc?.[curr], obj)" is something we have never never seen.

Comment: @Litmanen84 You can rewrite that as a normal `for` loop if you wish.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. In the end I've tried to make it more easy (and obviously longer) but at least I understand every thing I'm using. Thank you a lot!

Comment: will fail on keys containing []. : `people[0]['name.first']`

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev For an actual project, using Lodash's `_.get` would be far more appropriate than reimplementing it manually. This is a simple assignment and it does not seem necessary to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

### Building your own

As this is a [homework assignment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/), the goal should be to help you create your own version.

The most important part if figuring how to break this problem down into component parts.  It seems to me that there is a clear way to do so for this problem.

You have a string representing a path.  But a string is not the most useful tool here (unless you take the path given by Alexander Nenashev and try to turn your string into code with `eval`, or the `Function` constructor.  Note that if you do try that, your instructor is likely to pelt you with programming textbooks, not to mention giving you no credit for the assignment.)

Much more useful would be an array of node names.  Instead of `people[0].name`, it would be very useful to have `['people', 0, 'name']`.  This makes finding the nested property much easier (more below).

So with that breakdown, we have two goals:

- breaking the path down into constituent parts in an array
- using this new array, pull out the named properties  one at a time from a working object.

### Breaking down the path

Breaking the path down is the job of a parser.  Parsers are a big field, but we won't need the full power of general-purpose parsers because we're about to make some simplifying assumptions.  That means that we can parse with relatively simple tools.

#### Assumptions

We don't have full specifications for the input we may receive.  I would suggest that we start by trying to capture the sorts of input obviously similar to the test cases.  If the instructor comes back with more complex cases, you can rethink this.

This means that we should worry about simple properties only, string ones including only letter and digit characters, and number ones containing only digits.  This means that we're going to ignore the comments pointing out that some answers won't work for input such as `people[0]['name.first']`.  We need to be able to handle things like `people`, `0`, and `name`, but not objects with property names such as `'name.first'`.  If we later get additional requirements, we'll come back and refactor our solution to match.

#### Parsing

If we look at some sample paths, we might have simple things like `'city'`, somewhat more complex ones like `'people[0].name'`, or even more more complex ones like `'foo[0][42].bar[1].baz.qux[7]'`.  We can look at the punctuation between our component parts, things like `[`, `][`, `].`, `.`, and `]`.  One way to parse our input is to split the string at any of these bits of punctuation.

If you've already studied regular expressions, then they will make this simple enough, just call `String.prototype.replace`, passing an appropriate regular expression with the global flag.  But if you haven't done regex yet, one possibility would be to use `String.prototype.replaceAll` several times in a row, once for each of the punctuation strings you want, turning, say, `'foo[0][42].bar[1].baz.qux[7]'` into `'foo|0|42|bar|1|baz|qux|7|'`.  Then you can use `String.prototype.split` to turn that into `['foo', '0', '42', 'bar', '1', 'baz', 'qux', '7', '']`.  Note the empty string at the end.  We'll need to remove that, which we can do with `Array.prototype.filter`.

At this point, we have an array of strings, `['foo', '0', '42', 'bar', '1', 'baz', 'qux', '7']`  We originally said we wanted strings or integers, with the assumption that the integers would represent array indices.  We run into a small snag here, because it's perfectly legitimate to have an object with a property which looks like the string version of an array index: `{'1': 'foo', '2': 'bar'}`.  So how will we distinguish between actual array indices and object properties, between `0` and `'0'`?  The answer is simple enough: we don't have to!  JavaScript arrays are built on top of objects.  When you ask for property `0` from an array, it converts that to the string `'0'`.  So when *searching* for properties, this simply doesn't matter.  (If we were *constructing* objects using these paths, we would need somewhat better parsing.)

### Traversing our object

Now that we have our path in a convenient format, we need to walk along it, pulling out the appropriate objects at every step and returning the last one.

#### Recursive

If you've already studied recursion (if not, see next section), this would best be expressed with a recursive function.  If the path array is empty, we're done, and we return our input object.  If it's not, then we grab the property given in the first array entry from the object, and then recur using that result and the remainder of the path, returning the result of the recursion.

You will need to do some error processing, which can be done in either of two ways.  First, we can stop as soon as the sought-after property doesn't exist, either throwing an error or returning `undefined`.  Second, we could always look for the property on `(obj || {})`, giving ourselves a means to keep passing something useful through the chain of lookups, but still returning `undefined`.  The first of these is more efficient.  The second is arguably more elegant and is simpler to implement.

#### Iterative

Using your choice of a `for`-loop or a `while`-loop, you can loop through the elements of the array, updating a working object as you go.  When you're through with the loop, you can return the working object.

You have exactly the same error-checking responsibilities as mentioned in the `Recursive` section above.  You can either stop when the property doesn't exist -- again either throwing an error or returning `undefined` -- or you can make the working object `undefined` and eventually return at the end of the loop.  Here, I think the argument in favor of efficiency probably wins, since the iterative code is not particularly elegant to begin, continuing the loop does not seem to simplify our code any.

### Not the only breakdown

This is one approach to the problem.  There are certainly others.  The important thing, though, is to look to break complex problems down into simpler pieces.  If that involves adding intermediate data structures such as our array of node identifiers, it's almost never a problem.  And it can offer real benefit.

Comment: An really nice peace of human readable code. Thanks for the effort. Reminds me of the days where we actually had to start with prose of the above kind, providing every step of an algorithm in literal form, before being allowed to sit in front of a terminal.

Comment: @PeterSeliger: You must have been at this longer than I have.  Even back in college in the 80's, no one was insisting on this.  Just hack away at the VMS terminals!

Comment: I'm not that old, we just didn't have enough computers back then in Eastern Germany. Mid to end 80's in high school there was a mix of just 4 computers of the [Z 9001 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotron_KC_87) where one could lay hands on in a voluntarily chosen course in addition to the normal curriculum. During traineeship at [Robotron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEB_Robotron) assembler was practiced at terminals connected to an east block [ESER-mainfraim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ES_EVM). But I preferred TurboPascal [at this beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_1715).

Comment: Ahh, so just a few years younger: I graduated high school in 1984.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the path with a regular expression which removes speparators as well.

For getting a value, you could iterate the key, check if the key exist and assign the property value to `obj`.

Finally return `obj`.

```js
function findNestedValue(obj, path) {
    for (const key of path.match(/[^\[\]\.]+/g)) { // anything without [].
        if (!(key in obj)) return;
        obj = obj[key];
    }
    return obj;
}

const
    object = { people: [{ name: 'Alice', age: 30 }, { name: 'Bob', age: 25 }, { name: 'Charlie', age: 35 }], city: 'New York', year: 2023 };

console.log(findNestedValue(object, 'people[0].name')); // 'Alice'
console.log(findNestedValue(object, 'city')); // 'New York'
```

Comment: will fail on keys containing []. : `people[0]['name.first']`

Comment: yes, but it's not ment (as i see it). for having keys with some special characters `path` should be an array of keys instead of a string.